# Adobe air native extension application crashes on using FragmentActivity

Tags: air, adobe, android-fragmentactivity, air-native-extension

I am trying to work on a AIR native extension for android. So far i have worked on different type of stuff but seems i have hit the roof. Whenever i try to extend FragmentActivity rather than normal activity the application crashes as soon as the activity starts. I was also trying to use ActionbarSherlock, but the same thing happens. The moment i extend SherlockActivity, application crashed on starting that activity. Somebody please please help me with this.

```
package com.someone.mobile.android.extensions.aub;
```

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Comment: I have same a problem with you too :(. Hope someone help us!